# how to convince myself cos(A-B) proof works for all positions of A and B?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing

I managed to work this proof using a diagram. Then when I googled I found similar proofs. But aren't they incomplete? Because they prove the formula works only in first quadrant. Why do textbooks claim these are valid proofs even though they work only for a particular arrangement of rays $a$ and $b$ ?

How do we know that one proof is sufficient for all arrangements of rays $a$ and $b$ ?

[image]

Comment: The statement is true in general, but many such pictorial proofs heavily assume acute angles throughout. So, yes, such proofs are incomplete; to deduce the general case you probably have to invoke some periodicity/symmetry arguments to reduce to the case already known

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you, also if the length of $a$ is less than $b$, it is not obvious the same proof works. Ofcource  the formula works for all cases, but I feel a single proof does not make it obvious. Glad you agree with me XD

Comment: Can't you reduce the question to the first quadrant by using $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin(x)$ (so you need to prove the similar formula for $\sin$ simultaneously).

Comment: @JCAA I see, algebraic manipulation works. That's how my textbook worked this proof - by first proving cos(A+B) and asking to replace B with -B. However this doesn't feel satisfactory geometrically. When the angle increases, the projection of one vector onto other changes. Sometimes it is positive and some times it is negative. It is a bit magical how the formula gives the correct angle between the vectors no matter how the projections change...

Comment: The easiest way to prove these identities is by using some linear algebra, matrices of rotation through $A$ and $B$ and the fact that the rotation through $a+b$ is the composition of rotations through $a$ and through $b$.

Comment: The proof I know for $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$ is geometric but valid for any angle. The other formulas are derived from that one with a little algebra.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions)$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\left(A+B\right) & -\sin\left(A+B\right)\\
\sin\left(A+B\right) & \cos\left(A+B\right)
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos A & -\sin A\\
\sin A & \cos A
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos B & -\sin B\\
\sin B & \cos B
\end{array}\right)$$if you first prove an anticlockwise rotation by $A$ radians moves $\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)$ to $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos A & -\sin A\\
\sin A & \cos A
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)$. But this is trivial from the [circle-based definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Unit-circle_definitions) of the trigonometric functions: just separately check the cases $x=1,\,y=0$ and $x=0,\,y=-1$ (obtained from the first case with a anticlockwise right angle), and use linearity. Note if we compare this reasoning with $e^{i(A+B)}=e^{iA}e^{iB}$, we can read off a matrix representation of complex numbers:$$1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\,i=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$